# Is there a way to detect if my current wifi is different from the previously connected wifi?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-broadcastreceiver, android-networking, android-connectivitymanager

I am trying to figure out changed wifi connection while in the background. I want to make sure if my current wifi is same as previously connected wifi no action is taken while if its a new wifi that gets configured then I want my code to trigger. Any way we can check this currently ? would introduce a boolean var for checking wifi/network change.

Comment: How would you define a "changed wifi connection"?  If the IP changes? If you've connected to a different AP, on the same network?

Comment: For instance, I am on one wifi when my app is in the foreground, then my wifi switches to some other wifi while in the background then I want to be able to say my network/wifi changed. If the wifi does not change when I return to the foreground from background I dont want the wifi connected param to trigger.Currently I have registered a receiver in my activity which triggers wifi connected state everytime I return to foreground from background even if nothing was changed

Comment: I understand. My question is: What, to you, constitutes a change of wifi?  You could get an new IP address, while remaining connected to the same wifi connection (if DHCP expires).  Does that count as a change?  Or you could retain the same IP, but connect to a different access point, if you're on a large mesh network. Does that count as a change to you? You could also disconnect and re-connect to the same wifi. Does that count as a change to you? What if you connect to the same AP with the same IP, but renegotiate a different wifi protocol (e.g. from 802.11g to a/b). Is that a change?